# WooCommerce send welcome email to new user

Tags: woocommerce

Since I was using MiniOrange OTP plugin, new users don't get any welcome email from my site anymore. I asked the MiniOrange support about this but they haven't replied to me yet.

So can anyone help me? I need the welcome email sent to my users. What action/trigger/code that I need to send welcome email?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I can use this

```
$wc_emails = new WC_Email_Customer_New_Account();
$wc_emails->trigger($new_customerID, '', false);
```

to trigger WooCommerce to send welcome email.